# Most common "startswith" in a file to infer comment char

Tags: python, python-3.x, collections

I am trying to determine what comment character a file may be using. For example:

```
site,rank
#alexa.com/rankings
google.com,1
yahoo.com,2
```

Is there a way to get the most comment "startswith" path in a list, and intersect that with a set of possible comment characters? What I'm doing now is the following, but it seems quite naive:

```
POSSIBLE_COMMENT_CHARS = ['#', '//', '/*', '*/']

def get_comment_char(file):
    with open(file) as f:
        for line in f:
            for _char in POSSIBLE_COMMENT_CHARS:
                if line.startswith(_char):
                    return _char
```

With the above file data it would return:

```
get_comment_char(myalexafile)
>>> #
```

Comment: you're a lot into guessing those days :)

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre ha, a lot of user input I cannot control!

Comment: at least that one is answerable

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would match the start of the lines with a combination of your comment strings, then count the occurrences.

And finally compute the string with the max number of occurrences

```
text="""
site,rank
#alexa.com/rankings
google.com,1
#yahoo.com,2
//whatever
# another comment

"""

import collections,re

POSSIBLE_COMMENT_CHARS = ['#', '//', '/*', '*/']

c = collections.Counter(re.findall("^({})".format("|".join(re.escape(x) for x in POSSIBLE_COMMENT_CHARS)),
     text,flags=re.MULTILINE))

print(max(c,key=lambda k: c.get(k)))
```

prints `#`

be careful with `"|".join(re.escape(x) for x in POSSIBLE_COMMENT_CHARS` in the general case because it implies a linear search. If you have `5000` strings in your list it can be quite slow. Here it's ok.

Comment: thanks. This also gives me a lot of `//` though, which I have later on in the line in urls (mid-line, not at the start of the line). Here's an example output: `Counter({'//': 966, '#': 34})`

Comment: ah right, forgot to protect my expressions with () so `^` only applied to the first one!! fixed.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a `Counter` and a regex:

```
from collections import Counter
import re 

with open(fn) as f: 
    c=Counter(m.group(1) for line in f for m in re.finditer(r'^\s*(#|//|/\*|\*/)', line))

>>> c
Counter({'#': 1})
```

Comment: It looks simple but it is more than 3 times slower than the accepted answer

Comment: @hda: That is a silly comment without showing your work of timing it. The regex `r'^\s*(#|//|/\*|\*/)'` and `"|".join(re.escape(x) for x in POSSIBLE_COMMENT_CHARS)` is essentially the same regex.

Comment: i don’t think the regex is the problem but it’s definitely really slow and speed matters in this case